# Laravel 4 Present Model

Tags: php, rest, laravel

In Laravel 4, I have a model linking to a database table. Let's call it `Model`.

Say that this model has a database column called `Property A` and `Property B`.

When I make get request call to my model, i.e. `Model::all()` or `Model::find($id)`, I don't want to return `Property A` or `Property B`, but some kind of function of the two, which appears to the front-end as some kind of read-only field, i.e. `Property C`.

Do I need to use a presenter library here, or is there a way by overriding model functions within Laravel 4?

The key for me here is that the property shows up when I call `Model::all()`

**EDIT:**

From my understanding this should return an attribute with the name `foo` constantly with the value `"foo"`:

**Model**

```
class DiscountLink extends Eloquent {
    protected $table = 'discountLinks';
    protected $hidden = array('tag');
    protected $fillable = array('name', 'currency', 'language', 'price', 'instalments', 'expires', 'active', 'foo');

    public function getFooAttribute()
    {
        return "foo";
    }
}
```

**Controller**

```
class DiscountLinkController extends \BaseController {
    public function index()
    {
        return DiscountLink::all();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an [accessor](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#accessors-and-mutators) in your `Model`. To concatenate A and B, for instance:

```
public function getPropertyCAttribute()
{
    return $this->attributes['property_a'] . ' ' . $this->attributes['property_b'];
}
```

And then you can access `Model::find($id)->propertyC`.

If you want the attribute to be automatically included in your model's results array (e.g. if you're sending the results of `Model::all()` or `Model::get()` as JSON, for example), add an `$appends` declaration to the top of your model:

```
protected $appends = array('PropertyC');
```

---

If the function is something that can be done in the database (like concatenation, sum, etc.), you could also add a `DB::raw` command to your query, like:

```
Model::select(*, DB::raw('CONCAT(PropertyA, " ", PropertyA) AS PropertyC'))->...
```

Comment: Should `propertyC` appear when I call `Model::all()`?

Comment: Yes, once you loop over the results to access individual rows. So if you called `$model=Model::all()`, then you have access to `propertyC` inside `foreach ($model ad $m) { var_dump($m->propertyC) };`. Also, make sure the value in `$this->attributes['']` is the actual field name in your database; it is case-sensitive, so if your column is called `property_a`, the accessor should reference `$this->attributes['property_a'];`

Comment: Say I have this function:  `public function getFooAttribute()
  {
    return "goooglelelgoo";
  }` Then should I always have a property called Foo returned?

Comment: Yep, for each `$element` of your result set, at `$element->foo`.

Comment: Just not happening for me at the moment, I have updated my question with my full model.

Comment: Your model is correct. Show the code where you call `DiscountLink::all()` and try to access `foo`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63954/discussion-between-savvas-nicholas-and-damiani).